# How to install Dropbox on iPhone 3GS?

Tags: ios, iphone, dropbox

How can I install the Dropbox app on an iPhone 3GS running iOS 6.1.6? THe newest version of the app is iOS7-only.

I've heard that if the app has been installed under your account, the App Store will let you use the last compatible version, but I have no devices running iOS7 to add it to my account with.

How can I get the Dropbox app onto this phone? The iPhone is jailbroken.

Comment: What happens when you try to install the newest version? It should download the most compatible version.

Comment: @Robuust It just tells me I need iOS7. If the app is already listed as an app I own, it'll suggest the old versions, but the catch was getting the app onto my account in the first place. (@grgarside found a way to do it, though.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed, it will let you download the last compatible version if you already have the app in your purchase history. You can **add the app to your purchase history using iTunes** on your computer, since iTunes is version-agnostic. Once you've downloaded the app on iTunes, it will be in your purchase history and attempting to download it again on your device should prompt you to accept an older version of the app.

Comment: Yay! "Purchasing" Dropbox in iTunes enabled installation on the iPhone!

Answer (score -2):

If Dropbox is just compatible with iOs 7 then it would make a difference if you'll install it in your phone. It wouldn't run at all. Even your phone is jailbroken already, you can't find or install it from Cydia. It will just be from the Appstore.

I am using 4s running ios7.0.6 btw.

Comment: Could you clarify your answer? What do you mean by "*it would make a difference if you'll install it*"?

Comment: I've already checked Cydia for the old Dropbox version, and all the links in AppCake were dead.